# Permutation mapping of two lists in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, permutation

How can I create a permutation mapping of two lists in python?

For example I have two lists `[1,2,3]` and `['A','B','C']`

Then my code should generate a list of 6 dictionaries

```
[ {1:'A',2:'B',3:'C'},
  {1:'A',2:'C',3:'B'},
  {1:'B',2:'A',3:'C'},
  {1:'B',2:'C',3:'A'},
  {1:'C',2:'A',3:'B'},
  {1:'C',2:'B',3:'A'} ]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) in a list comprehension:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> L1 = [1,2,3]
>>> L2 = ['A','B','C']
>>> [dict(zip(L1, p)) for p in permutations(L2)]
[{1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'},
 {1: 'A', 2: 'C', 3: 'B'},
 {1: 'B', 2: 'A', 3: 'C'},
 {1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'A'},
 {1: 'C', 2: 'A', 3: 'B'},
 {1: 'C', 2: 'B', 3: 'A'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to permutate only the values of the dicts, so you could do something like

```
from itertools import permutations

dicts = []


keys = [1, 2, 3]
for values in permutations(['A', 'B', 'C']):
    new_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
    dicts.append(new_dict)
```