Get all tuple permutations between two lists
Given two lists of length n, I've been trying to find a pythonic way to return a list of a list of n-tuples where each list of tuples is a distinct permutation of the possible values between the two lists. So given:
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]

I'd expect an output of:
[ [(1, 3), (2, 4)], [(1, 4), (2, 3)] ]

I looked at questions like permutations of two lists in python, but that's not quite what I'm after. I looked at the itertools library and nothing immediately popped out at me.
What's a good pythonic way to solve this?

It's essentially the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268745/permutation-mapping-of-two-lists-in-python, only with lists of tuples as desired result instead of dictionaries (which means the solution can be reused by changing dict to list).

You could do it that way
[list(zip(x,b)) for x in itertools.permutations(a)]

What you really want is, after all, permutations of one of the list, and all possible matching. So it is more a permutations problem than a product problem. So here, I choose to keep b as is, and try all possible orders for a, and zip those permutations of a with b

Why did you choose b when they chose a?

@nocomment For no specific reason. I didn't feel that a given order of the tuples in the sublist was important (at least question didn't say otherwise). As long as all possible matchings are enumerated. But indeed, if it is important, and if we want to obtain same order (that is in each sublist, first element of tuple appears always in the same order as a, so [[(a1,...),(a2,...),(a3,...),...], [(a1, ...),(a2,...),(a3,...),...], ...], then we could fix a and permute b: [list(zip(a,x)) for x in itertools.permutations(b)]
